# How to keep the VBScript command window open during execution

Tags: vbscript, command-window

When I execute a VBScript, the command window that it creates closes quickly before the user gets a chance to read the output. How can I get the window to stay open without modifying windows registry?

This is the code:

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.shell") 
objShell.Run "SyncToyCmd.exe -R", 1, True
```

Comment: The previously existing command line window, from which you execute your script, closes? I've never seen that happen. Or do you mean, a VBScript executed from Windows Explorer? What version of Windows are you using?

Comment: Jean-Francois Corbett is right, I can't see the cmd window that you executed the script inside closing, surely it should just give you a new cmd line?

Comment: @Jean-FrancoisCorbett  i am not talking about the window from which i execute the script. When the script starts executing a new window pops up and closes quickly. I am using windows 7.

Comment: Are you specifically opening a command-line window in your script? Or is this just something that always happens automatically when you run a script? (That doesn't happen for me.) Please show us (the relevant portions of) your code.

Comment: @Jean-FrancoisCorbett  
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.shell")  
objShell.Run "SyncToyCmd.exe -R", 1, True

Comment: Thanks. Now we can answer... see below.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can send your execution command through the `cmd.exe` command interpreter, along with a pause command which will give the user a `Press any key to continue . . .` prompt to close the window.

```
objShell.run "%comspec% /c ""SyncToyCmd.exe -R & pause""", 1, True
```

Or to keep the window alive, use the `/k` flag instead of `/c`:

```
objShell.run "%comspec% /k SyncToyCmd.exe -R", 1, True
```

But beware, your VBScript will not continue (or terminate) until this cmd window is manually closed.

The `%comspec%` environment variable refers to the correct command to open the command interpreter as per your operating system. On my XP machine, for instance, `%comspec%` is equal to `C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe`.

See `cmd.exe` documentation here: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/cmd.mspx?mfr=true

More info on the use of the `&` versus the `&&` command separators [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28891643/2662901).

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that it's the popped-up command window that you want to keep open (rather than the one running your VBScript), you can use `CMD.exe`'s `Pause` command to achieve this:

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.shell") 
objShell.Run "cmd.exe /C ""SyncToyCmd.exe -R & Pause"" ", 1, True
```

Answer (score -3):

Make it sleep for a while, maybe tell the user it will close in 5 seconds?

```
Set WScript = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
WScript.Sleep 5000
```

Comment: Why throw the user into a panic with a "this message will self-destruct in 5 seconds"? Better to let the user choose when it will close.

Comment: If you give them enough time it won't make them "panic" and by using a message like I suggested the user would know when it would close, also using a messagebox might obscure the view of the results of the app meaning that they have to move it out of the way to see anything

Comment: Oops, given the clarified question, this won't work, and neither will my original answer...

Comment: -1 because the WScript.Shell object is not the WScript object (so the first statement clobbers the 'real' WScript that has a .Sleep method) and has no .Sleep method.

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner That was my answer before the original question was edited/revised as was Jean's first answer

Comment: @Bali C: the order of publication is irrelevant - your code is wrong and should be corrected.