# Sending Many Command, Input and Keep the CMD Alive

Tags: windows, vbscript, cmd

I try to send second command to cmd.
in cmd maybe i should do this

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14986]
(c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
C:\WINDOWS\system32>D:
D:\>set /p a=Write a text :
Write a text : This is a sample
D:\>echo %a% > sample.txt
D:\>type sample.txt
This is a sample
D:\>
```

Change to drive D > set a variable > write the answer > write it to a file and read it. 
inline code is : 
 
`cmd.exe /c "D: & set/p a=write a text : & echo %a% > sample.txt & type sample.txt & pause"`

its sucks when i want to use it in VB Script. while i try to get command, i will take it out to file. But how if there is a input request like :

```
Press any key to continue...
Are you sure you want to continue? (Y/n)
Ping an IP : (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)
```

and when i send command to it. it will auto exit if its finish the task like

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").run "cmd.exe /c ping google.com > myfile.txt
'After finish pinging it will auto exit.
```

And my question are, how i send input to cmd. And how i KEEP the cmd still live 
Any ideas? 
Oh ya. I wont to use batch-file to execute it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to keep the vb-script command window open during execution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7526598/how-to-keep-the-vb-script-command-window-open-during-execution)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility would be to use pipe communication between your VB6 process and your cmd process. Please have a look on below Windows API functions:

1. `CreatePipe` (kernel32)
2. `CreateProcess` (kernel32) => cmd without /c flag
3. `ReadFile`/`WriteFile` on pipe handles to read/write cmd input/ouput

[Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

**Pause** and **cmd /k**  should do your work.

See the [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17957076/keep-cmd-open-after-bat-file-executes) for reference.

IN VBA, you can do something like this:

```
Set objShell = CreateObject(“Wscript.Shell”)

objShell.Run(“%comspec% /k ipconfig /all”)
```

Here is another [VBscript reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7526598/how-to-keep-the-vb-script-command-window-open-during-execution)

Comment: Technically it just make the cmd keep alive and cannot send any command to it. Then, My question is how i send the second command or send input for input request like `Press any key to continue...` / `Are you sure you want to continue?(Y/n)` `IP : (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)` without `&` or `-F` `/y` parameter

Comment: @FarhanMSabran : I recommend using the `/Q` option instead, but the pipe technique might be important if you ever run into a command that does not provide an option to suppress confirmation messages.