# VBScript Command window - passing a command syntax

Tags: vbscript, command-window

I'm trying to get a command to run in a cmd vindow via VBS.  Just like this answer:
[How to keep the VBScript command window open during execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7526598/how-to-keep-the-vbscript-command-window-open-during-execution/44270667?noredirect=1#comment75549338_44270667)

The command I'm trying to issue is this, as written it works in a .cmd file.

```
"\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\dtexec" /x86 /f "\\path\folder\folder with space\Import.dtsx"
```

I've been unable to get it to work in the syntax from the above answer:

```
objShell.run "%comspec% /c ""SomeProgram.exe -R & pause""", 1, True
```

Figure it's a double quote issue, but I can't find it.

(I have to use the whole path to dtexec to force usage of the 16bit version.)

Followup:  =======================================================

This works:

```
oShell.Run "%comspec% /C ""\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\dtexec"" /x86 /f c:\temp\Import.dtsx & Pause", 1, True
```

This does not:

```
oShell.Run "%comspec% /C ""\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\dtexec"" /x86 /f ""c:\temp\temp two\Import.dtsx"" & Pause", 1, True
```

nor this:

```
oShell.Run "%comspec% /C ""\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\dtexec /x86 /f c:\temp\temp two\Import.dtsx"" & Pause", 1, True
```

It's that space in the filename argument that is hosing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `pause`, just tell CMD to keep the window open after the command finishes (`/k`) instead of closing it (`/c`):

```
objShell.Run "%comspec% /k program.exe -R", 1, True
```

Nested double quotes are only required when you have a path with spaces in it, e.g.:

```
objShell.Run "%comspec% /k ""C:\some folder\program.exe"" -R", 1, True
```

**Edit:** If arguments in your commandline are paths with spaces as well you need quotes around each path and another set of quotes around the entire statement:

```
objShell.Run "%comspec% /c """"C:\some folder\program.exe"" /p ""foo bar"" & pause""", 1, True
```

Comment: I wanted to use the /c syntax for the "press any key" to close.  I got that working in my follow-up above.  BUT when the filename argument also has a space, it will not work as I have it written.  Tried every which way, clearly missing the right way.