# WScript.Shell not opening command window

Tags: vbscript

I have an executable `EMC_WS.EXE` and I want to run this using the command

```
WshShell.Run "EMC_WS.EXE", 1, False
```

The executable runs correctly, but the command window is not appearing. I have used mingwstudio to generate `EMC_WS.EXE`.

```
Dim pathString, UserPath
Dim position
Dim WshShell, Shell

Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set Shell = WshShell.Environment("User")

strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colProcessList = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name = 'EMC_WS.EXE'")

For Each objProcess In colProcessList
    objProcess.Terminate()
Next

WshShell.Run "EMC_WS.EXE", 1, False

Set WshShell = Nothing
WScript.Quit(0)
```

Comment: how is it related to [tag:c] ?

Comment: removed c and javascript tags as the question is for vbscript only

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to keep the VBScript command window open during execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7526598/how-to-keep-the-vbscript-command-window-open-during-execution)

Comment: Did you build `emc_ws.exe` as a console application?